# Can the following sequence be shown to necessarily exist w/o AoC?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Considering any proper subset $S$ of the real numbers that is bounded above and contains infinitely many elements, $S$ necessarily contains a *non-decreasing* sequence $(s_n)$ with the following property:

$$\forall \alpha \in S, \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \textrm{ such that $\alpha \leq s_n$}?$$

**PROOF**

Note: By $(s_n) \subset S,$ I mean a sequence $(s_n)$ that is fully contained in the set $S.$ Excuse this notation if it is improper.

Suppose

$$\exists \alpha \in S \text{ such that } \forall (s_n) \subset S \textrm{ it follows that } \alpha > s_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

There is an immediate contradiction, for consider any sequence $(s_n)$ such that for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ $$\forall n \geq N, s_n = \alpha.$$

Hence, $\forall \alpha \in S,$ if $\alpha > s_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N},$ $\forall (s_n) \subset S \rightarrow$ contradiction. Hence, there necessarily exists such a sequence.

---

**Does this proof employ bad reasoning? If so, where?**

Comment: There is a flaw. Hint: what happens if $S$ contains a maximal element?

Comment: such as $[0,1] \cup \{2\}?$ Or something like that

Comment: For example. Even $[0,1]$ itself would be fine.

Comment: Any monotone sequence such that for some $N \in \mathbb{N},$ $s_n = 1, \forall n \geq N.$ And pick $N-1$ elements in $[0,1]$ such that $s_i \leq s_{i+1}$ for $i \leq N.$ I'm sorry if something is obvious and I'm missing it ><

Comment: I have understood "monotone increasing" as *strictly* increasing. If you allow the eventually constant sequence then everything is fine.

Comment: Oh. Ya. That's how my textbook defined it. Sorry for the confusion. Should I rename it to something else?

Comment: An unambiguous name would be "nondecreasing".

Comment: Ok. I will change that now. Thanks wojowu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is impermissibly switching around quantifiers. You want to prove
$$ \tag{1} \exists (s_n)\; \forall \alpha \; \exists n : s_n \ge \alpha $$
If you want to do that by an indirect proof, you need to start by assuming the *negation* of this, which is
$$ \tag{2} \forall (s_n) \; \exists \alpha \; \forall n : s_n < \alpha $$
But what you're *actually* assuming is something different, namely
$$ \tag{3} \exists \alpha \; \forall (s_n) \; \forall n : s_n < \alpha $$
But (3) is a stronger assumption than (2) -- it says you can find an $\alpha$ that *does not* depend on $(s_n)$, which the $\alpha$ in (2) is allowed to. Therefore (3) is a stronger assumption than the one an indirect proof allows you to make.

As a concrete example of (3) being stronger, note that if we let $\alpha$ and the $s_i$s range over $\omega_1$ (with its natural ordering) instead of a subset of $\mathbb R$, then (2) becomes true, whereas (3) is false.

---

I don't know if your claim can be proved without the axiom of choice. Intuitively I think it has the feeling of something that might well require choice.

You don't need much choice, as those things go, though. Countable choice (which is a quite weak choice principle) will easily do.

Comment: Indeed, it is consistent that there is a subset of $(0,1)$ which is infinite but has no countably infinite subset. So countable choice is probably enough.